# unable to display data for angularjs ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

Can any one help me why data is not appearing for my ui grids. Please find the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YV5GrvTWKwwQKbIZuxRB?p=preview). The following is my template.

```
<div class="innerChartsDiv">
    <div class="col">
        <p class="graphtitle">Summary 0 Grid </p>
        <div class="myGrid" ui-grid="gridOptionsZero"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p class="graphtitle">Summary 1 Grid </p>
        <div class="myGrid" ui-grid="gridOptionsOne"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, not yet still waiting

Comment: i checked your plunkr, but its really hard to understand by code, could you update the question with few lines, what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I am in the process of migrating to ui grid from ng grid. The following is the reference plunker for my 'summary 0 Grid'. http://plnkr.co/edit/2UouUZuChllyYcQchoBK?p=preview. Here it is ng grid code the same I am trying to make it work in ui grid.

Comment: For 'Summary 1 Grid', I am using http://plnkr.co/edit/lPCjNDThanZOZtKShd3z?p=preview. I am trying to convert this ng grid code to ui grid.

Comment: Please let me know if you want me to make any further clarification on this.

Comment: 'Summary 0 Grid' is handling dynamic models for title and 'Summary 1 Grid' is some special type requirement for which I need to repeat same columns for different quarters.